# How can I create recurring appointments in the calendar?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, you can create guild events in the built-in calendar, however creating events that recur is extremely painful. You can copy an event, but there is a time limit between creating events, thus mass pasting takes several minutes for each event.

Is there a more straightforward way to create events in the calendar that repeat on a certain schedule, such as weekly?

Comment: I do not believe so, as you've mentioned you can copy and paste the events to create duplicates on new days but there isn't a method of bypassing the the limit on how quickly you can create the events.

Answer (score 1):

Without Addons, there is no way doing this. However, you can use the addon [group calendar](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/group-calendar), which makes it possible to create repeating events.